Reset a nested property in ref didn't update v-model
How can I reset a ref and update a v-model which is pointing to child property in my ref?
I create this initState object and set it to a ref object
const initState = {
  text: {
    value: "",
    isDirty: false,
  },
};

const form = ref(initState);

Then I create a reset function to reset value of v-model
const reset = () => {
  // doesn't work
  // form.value = initState;

  // work
  form.value = {
    text: {
      value: "",
      isDirty: false,
    },
  };
};

Here is my template
<template>
  <form>
    <input v-model="form.text.value" placeholder="enter text..." />
    <button @click.prevent="reset">reset</button>
  </form>
  <div>{{ form.text.value }}</div>
</template>

Here is my demo code
https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-morning-ymxq3v
It didn't work if I set that ref directly by initState variable
But it did successfully work if I assign object which is the same with initState
const reset = () => {
  // doesn't work
  // form.value = initState;

  // work
  form.value = {
    text: {
      value: "",
      isDirty: false,
    },
  };
};


This because the Objects are reference types,and you can test this
const reset = () => {
  console.log(form.value.text.value === initState.text.value )   
  //  always be true
};

so a better way is to use function instead.
const initState = ()=> ({
  text: {
    value: "",
    isDirty: false,
  }
});
const form = ref(initState ())
const reset = () => {
  form.value = initState ()
};


Thanks @moon
I change this initState to a function and can successfully reset
v-model is updated as expected
Thanks
